# ReactiveUI and casting in WhenAny

Tags: c#, reactiveui

What I am doing is this:

```
Item.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    if(sender is IInterface)
        DoSomethingWith(((IInterface)sender).PropertyFromInterface);
}
```

how would I go about implementing such a stream in RxUI?

I tried this:

```
this.WhenAny(x => (x.Item as IInterface).PropertyFromInterface, x.GetValue())
    .Subscribe(DoSomethingWith);
```

but it seems that is not possible to do.

Would I have to make a property like this? ->

```
private IInterface ItemAsInterface { get { return Item as IInterface; } }
```

I made a workaround for now like this:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.Item, x => x.GetValue()).OfType<IInterface>()
    .Select(x => x.PropertyFromInterface).DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Subscribe(DoSomethingWith);
```

but what I actually want is getting the propertychanged updates for "PropertyFromInterface" while Item is of IInterface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked back with my old questions, I was looking for something like this solution:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.Item, x => x.GetValue())
    .OfType<IInterface>()
    .Select(x => x.WhenAny(y => y.PropertyFromInterface, y => y.Value)
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(DoSomethingWith);
```

The missing link for me was the .Switch method.

Additionally, I wanted the observable to not do anything if the property is NOT of the needed type:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.Item, x => x.Value as IInterface)
    .Select(x => x == null ? 
         Observable.Empty : 
         x.WhenAny(y => y.PropertyFromInterface, y => y.Value)
    .Switch()
    .Subscribe(DoSomethingWith);
```

(e.g. When I set `this.Item` to an instance of `IInterface`, I wanted `DoSomethingWith` to listen to changes to that instance's `PropertyFromInterface`, and when `this.Item` gets set to something different, the observable should not continue to fire until `this.Item` is an instance of `IInterface` again.)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.Item, x => x.Value as IInterface)
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Subscribe(DoSomethingWith);
```

**Update:** Ok, I vaguely understand what you want to do now - here's how I would do it:

```
public ViewModelBase()
{
    // Once the object is set up, initialize it if it's an IInterface
    RxApp.MainThreadScheduler.Schedule(() => {
        var someInterface = this as IInterface;
        if (someInterface == null) return;

        DoSomethingWith(someInterface.PropertyFromInterface);
    });
}
```

If you *really* want to initialize it via PropertyChanged:

```
this.Changed
    .Select(x => x.Sender as IInterface)
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Take(1)   // Unsubs automatically once we've done a thing
    .Subscribe(x => DoSomethingWith(x.PropertyFromInterface));
```

Comment: I want to bind to property defined on the interface, not the object itself. This would throw whenever the Item itself would be replaced, not when it's property is changed. Adding something to the OP to clarify.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? I have no idea why you'd want such a construct

Comment: I have a conductor viewmodel with a viewmodelbase as Item. If the item currently is of a certain interface, a certain property it then has should be observed. Before, I registered/unregistered to propertychanged on the item (whenever it was replaced) and asked if it is of the interface. I was hoping I could drop the register/unregister and write an observable which would do the job by itself.